# Can't adjust weights in linear layout - android

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, android-linearlayout

I've searched but couldn't figure out the problem.

[image]

I want to make exactly like the above picture. I've used linear layout in vertical for the "Day Teams   Score    Status"
And then for the content containing the values of above headings, I've used a listview.

What I've achieved is that headings "Day Teams   Score    Status" are being shown with spaces but the contents ( which are in seperate .xml file ) are not being shown with spaces, so what I'm getting is:

[image]

The adapter xml file for the list view is:

**adapter_my_matches.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Date"
        android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Teams"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTeams1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Teams"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTeams2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Score"
        android:id="@+id/textViewScore"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Status"
        android:id="@+id/textViewStatus"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yeah this is a running code, but giving unexpected layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the layout you are looking for.Let me know if anything going bad. Here the weight i set for a sample, you can change it according to your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum= "6">
         <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Date"
        android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Teams"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTeams1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>


        <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Score"
        android:id="@+id/textViewScore"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:gravity="center"
         />

       <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Status"
        android:id="@+id/textViewStatus"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:gravity="center"
         />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum= "6">
         <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="12 Feb"
        android:id="@+id/textViewDate1"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="IND VS PAK"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTeams11"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>


        <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="256"
        android:id="@+id/textViewScore1"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

       <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="WIN"
        android:id="@+id/textViewStatus1"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:gravity="center"
         />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks bro it worked! Can you please mention the problem with my code?

Comment: I checked the issue bro, for me if the text is big its displaying in the next line :( .

Comment: Ok thanks, Can you please tell me what was wrong with my code?

Comment: In your code 1. You have to mention the Weightsum, 2. give the weight value according to the need, 3.  Always android:layout_width = "0" for using weight based on width. can you plz accept the answer if worked +1 :P

Comment: I'll do it after this last question. I got this problem because android is not officially taught in my university (only java is taught) and I'm learning myself by doing work, and googling. Is there a way to avoid such mistakes for me in future? What should I do. Should I study book first or what?

Comment: You are doing the right job and searching online the best, understand what data you are using is, and learn more about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70896/discussion-between-muhammad-rehan-qadri-and-remees-m-syde).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your linearlayout code

```
android:weightSum="0.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

give layout_weight to parent layout and give weight to child element and make sure that layout_weight should be sum of its all child's weight total. make width of child as warp_content.

Comment: whose width should I set to wrap content. The last sentence of your answer is vague. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Use this One :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="8" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTeams1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Teams"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTeams2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Teams"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewScore"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Score"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStatus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Status"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: same problem. You would have scene your code working on your android studio preview of xml. But when you run on emulator or real device, it doesn't show as expected. Getting same problem.

Comment: exactly. Actually the gap between every column.

Comment: for empty views set empty string

Comment: Removed the text from the xml of every textview, but no effect.